# Differences in sqlite on simulator/devices

Tags: iphone, objective-c, database, sqlite, ios-simulator

I have an app pulling information from a SQLite database. It works perfectly on the iPhone Simulator, but I don't get anything when I test on a device. Are there differences to using a database between the two? I've tried looking all over and can't find anything that is helping. I see this problem is common on google, I just haven't found a solution thats worked for me.

I have put break points in and tried to debug this, on the actual device it never gets passed `while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)`, it is always returning `SQLITE_DONE`. I can't figure out why this would change on a device. Any help would be appreciated, advice on SQLite, or if the code could be improved etc. Thanks.

```
NSString *qsql = @"SELECT Distinct State FROM School";
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [qsql UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK) 
    {
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) 
        {
            char *colState = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0);
        NSString *state = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:colState];

        [states addObject:state];
        [state release];
    }
    sqlite3_reset(statement);
}
return states;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind is that the database is installed properly on the simulator but not on the phone.

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717108/where-would-you-place-your-sqlite-database-file-in-an-iphone-app) to see if it helps you.

Comment: verify that your app actually finds the DB file itself.