# FMDB initialisation and Upgrade database version in iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite, fmdb

I am using FMDB and Sqllite for my iOS application. I know about how to create Database and Table programatically but i am confuse where to write code so, it run first time. If i write code in **application:didFinishLaunching** method then it run every time when i open app. Is there any methode where I can Initialise/Create Database and Database Tables?

Another question is suppose I need to do some changes in database when upload new version of app then in which methode i need to write code so, it execute first time only?

Looking forward to hear from you.

Thank You,
Shailesh

Answer (score 3):

For the second question you need to have a version number

http://ccgus.github.io/fmdb/html/Categories/FMDatabase+FMDatabaseAdditions.html#//api/name/userVersion

```
FMDatabase *db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:PATH];
uint32_t version = [db userVersion]
```

and check against a number version in your code , if the database version number is less than your code version number , call a method for to do the upgrade

you should to place  this verification in the applicationdidFinishLaunching method

Answer (score 1):

You can check if sqlite file exists in Documents directory of your sandbox so if exists, you can make sure you already initialised/created DB and DB Tables.

Comment: From this answer You are not execute your database creation method every time when app is open.

Comment: Hi Thank you very much for your kind reply. Yes that is the solution but for this i need to check every time. Is there any methode where I can simply initialise. If suppose i need to do any changes in database when i upload version of app then there is any methode?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check every time the app opens if the database exists this code will do it. Put it in application willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9303745/5465258