# Failed to open database with message 'no such table: recentlyViewd'

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I am trying to read the data from a local database file . But I am getting following error ...
  Failed to open database with message 'no such table: recentlyViewd'.

```
sqlite3_stmt *statement = NULL;
sqlite3 *database;
NSString *sqLiteDb = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"databaseFile"
                                                     ofType:@"db"];

NSLog(@"%s",[sqLiteDb UTF8String]);
if (sqlite3_open([sqLiteDb UTF8String], &database) != SQLITE_OK) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to open database!");
}
//NSLog(@" %d, %d ",sqlite3_step(statement),SQLITE_ROW);
const char *sql = "SELECT ID FROM recentlyViewd";
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
    while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        int primaryKey = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
        NSLog(@"%d",primaryKey);

    }
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Failed to open database with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    sqlite3_close(database);
}

if (statement) {
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
```

Here I am just trying to open and read the database file.

Comment: Move the `NSLog` call *before* the `sqlite3_close` call.

Comment: Got that ... It prints "Failed to open database with message 'no such table: recentlyViewd'".
Again It runs fine in simulator but same error occurs when I run this app on device

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where would you place your SQLite database file in an iPhone app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717108/where-would-you-place-your-sqlite-database-file-in-an-iphone-app)

Comment: Basically you cannot open the database in read/write mode from within the app bundle.  What you normally do is copy it to your documents folder if it doesn't already exist.